# Which is finer(larger) between the sequence spaces $l_{p}$ & $l_{p+1}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Prove that, $l_{3}\subset l_{7}$ & $L_{9}[0,1]\subset L_{6}[0,1]$, where $l_{p}$ & $L_{p}[0,1]$ are of usual notation.

Are the converses hold for both cases?

Can these two results generalized for any $p(1\le p<\infty)$ ?

I only know that, $l_{p}(1<p<\infty)$ is not a subset of $l_{1}$.

For ex. consider the sequence, $\{x_{n}\}=\{\dfrac{1}{n}\}$. Then, $\{x_{n}\}\in l_{p}$ for any $p(1< p<\infty)$ but $\{x_{n}\}\notin l_{1}$.

How I prove these directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've already basically worked out the logic. The case for $l_1$ can be easily generalised.
Suppose $\{ x_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l_p$, then $(\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n|^p)^{1/n}<\infty $ and so $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n|^p<\infty $. Therefore there exists an $N$ such that for arbitrary $n>N$, $|x_n|^p<1$. i.e $|x_n|<1$. And so for any $n>N$, $|x_n|^{p+1} < |x_n|^p$. Therefore $\sum^\infty_{n=N+1}|x_n|^{p+1} < \sum^\infty_{n=N+1}|x_n|^{p} < \infty $ and so $\{ x_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l_{p+1}$.

EDIT:
I initially claimed here that the $L_p$ case was analogous which is completely wrong, viewers should read the comments for the answer to the rest of the question.

Comment: How there exists an $N$ such that for arbitrary $n>N$, $|x_n|^p<1$?

Comment: Suppose the contrary, that there does not exist such an $N$, then you could find infinitely many $n$ with $|x_n|^p>1$ and the collective sum of these would add to give a divergent sum, and so your sequence would not lie in $l_p$

The crux of the argument is that, for a sequence to lie in $l_p$, its sum much converge and so at some point the terms of the sequence have to start converging to zero (as you will see proved in any first course in analysis). Because of this, what is really imprtant is how fast the terms converge to zero. In l_1 the contraint is that they must converge very fast to

Comment: zero. Whereas for $l_{1000}$, for example, the terms wont have to converge to zero so fast because they are being raised to the power 1000 which significantly speeds up the convergence. Hence the condition to lie in $l_{1000}$ is much looser than that for $l_1$, and so in a sense $l_{1000}$ is bigger.

This concept is the same as the one which shows $L_p$ is contained in $L_{p+1}$, and once you have understood it you can cement your understanding by doing the proof for that. Whoch is why I'm only answering the first part :)

Comment: But I saw $L_{p+1}$ is contained in $L_{p}$..Was it wrong?

Comment: My apologies! I was just assuming that the first proof would carry over verbatim, which I can now see it does not. Having tried to prove it myself I now see I was being naive so very sorry to have confused you there. 
According to wikipedia, all $L_p$ norms are equilvalent for $p<\infty$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Relations_between_p-norms
Note the inequality on relations between norms. This would imply that the function spaces are the same size. I will think more about this and let you know if I have an insight, though maybe someone else on stackexchange will help us out.

Comment: What I said about $l_p$ spaces is certainly true, it's just the $L_9$ contained in $L_6$ that we need to show now. Sorry again!

Comment: Ah ok so I'm sorry again to have confused you yesterday. I now have a better answer. The problem isn't so hard because we are only dealing on the closed interval $[0,1]$ which means that for a function to belong to $L_(p+1)$, the only condition is that it doesn't asymptote to infinity too fast when its modulus is raised to the power $p+1$ within the interval. If it obeys this condition, then necessarily it will not asymptote to infinity too fast when raised to the lesser power $p$. 
I'll make that argument more formal. Let $f$ be a function on the closed unit interval and define $\tilde{f}$

Comment: define $\tilde{f}$ by $\tilde{f}(x)=\mathrm{max}\{ |f(x)|,1 \}$. Then one can easily check that $f \in L_p[0,1]$ if and only if $\tilde{f} \in L_p[0,1]$. Now, given $f \in L_{p+1}[0,1]$, we have $|\tilde{f}(x)|^p < |\tilde{f}(x)|^{p+1}$ which implies that $\tilde{f} \in L_p[0,1]$. And so $f \in L_p[0,1]$

Comment: I hope you can see that the argument would break down for $L_p(\mathbb{R})$, where there are two conditions for a function to belong to the space. Firstly, that the function does not asymptote to infinity 'too fast' and secondly that the function tends to zero 'fast enough' as we approach infinity in the domain $\mathbb{R}$.
To seal up the rest of your question, $L_p[0,1]$ is not contained in $L_{p+1}[0,1]$, as the function $f(x)=(x-\frac{1}{2})^{-(p+1)^{-1}}$ demonstrates.